# Accommodation Listing Plugin for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, listings

Hey Guys, is there a wordpress plugin that allows admin to add accommodation listings? I would like to modify fields, upload images etc etc

Ive looked in the plugins and not one of them is a real solution

What I need is a plugin that will allow me to add the images, change the fields, etc and then also display it as a typical listing, ie photo, description, maybe a field or two, price

And when you click on it, it'll take you to the full detailed page....

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: My vote: drop Wordpress for a CMS more geared toward custom content types.

Comment: I'll investigate that, can you suggest a CMS?

Comment: Drupal would be my suggestion, but it has a pretty steep learning curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go this route. Not a plugin, but if you're a serious agent, this is a nice way to go.

http://www.studiopress.com/themes/agentpress